# Copying from a directory without using os.chdir()

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

The program should backup files in a source folder to a zip file in destination, and keep track of how many versions there are (which explains the shelve). In order to copy these files, apparently I have to change the `cwd` to the source path (folder), because otherwise the program will not detect them. While it may not seem to cause that much of an issue, my OCD triggers when I see the shelve files in the new `.zip` folder. I thought about adding lines to delete the shelve files, but I was wondering if there is some other way.

(This program is a project in a certain book I'm reading, and while the project demanded a more basic version of this, I like to take it a step forward.)

```
import os, shelve, zipfile

def backupToZip(folder, destination, copies=1):

#Folder
    fName= os.path.basename(folder)

#Shelfing for copy number
    namesNums = shelve.open('names')
    if fName not in namesNums:
        num= 1
        namesNums[fName]= num
    else:
        num= namesNums[fName]

#Producing zips
    os.chdir(folder)
    for i in range(int(copies)):
        zipPath= os.path.join(destination, fName+'_'+str(num)+'.zip')
        theZip= zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w')

        for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for filename in filenames:
                theZip.write(filename)
        num+=1

    namesNums[fName]= num
    namesNums.close()
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) The title of your question does not comply with [State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) While *any aspect of the code posted is fair game*, it may be useful to pose explicit questions in the question body.

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for the welcome! I will keep that in mind in my future posts/questions (will edit this one as well later on).

Answer (score 2):

- [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) supports all methods that [`dict`ionarys do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

  > Shelf objects support all methods supported by dictionaries. This eases the transition from dictionary based scripts to those requiring persistent storage.

  And so you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), rather than your `if-else`.
- Rather than using `num += 1`, you can use `range(num, num + copies)`. Since `num` is defined in an outer scope, you can use it after the `for` loop too.
- Rather than using string concatination, you can use f-strings in Python 3.6+ or format strings:

  ```
  # yours
  fName+'_'+str(num)+'.zip'
  # f-string
  f'{fName}_{num}.zip'
  # string format
  '{}_{}.zip'.format(fName, num)
  '{fName}_{num}.zip'.format(fName=fName, num=num)
  ```
- It's simpler to use `with` when handling content managers. And so you should use them on `shelve.open` and `zipfile.ZipFile`.

  Not only does it make you not have to learn how to close all types of context managers. The context will be closed in the case of an error too.
- Don't use `CamelCase` or `camelCase`, instead use `snake_case`.
- Use `_` as a 'throw away' variable. Some people, however, like to instead use `__`.
- Put a space either side of your equal signs. `a = b`, not `a= b`.

This can become:

```
import os, shelve, zipfile

def backup_to_zip(folder, destination, copies=1):
    f_name= os.path.basename(folder)
    with shelve.open('names') as names:
        num = names.setdafault(f_name, 1)

        os.chdir(folder)
        for num in range(num, num + copies):
            zip_path = os.path.join(destination, f'{f_name}_{num}.zip')
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, 'w') as the_zip:
                for _, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
                    for filename in filenames:
                        the_zip.write(filename)

        names[f_name] = num
```

You could also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) rather than `os.path`. Which may allow you to use:

```
def backup_to_zip(folder, destination, copies=1):
    folder = Path(folder)

    with shelve.open('names') as names:
        num = names.setdefault(folder.name, 1)
        path = folder / Path(destination)
        for num in range(num, num + copies):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(path / f'{folder.name}_{num}.zip', 'w') as f:
                for file in folder.iterdir():
                    if file.is_file():
                        f.write(file.name)

        names[folder.name] = num
```

Comment: okay so I got 4 things to point out: 1) So using `with - as` closes the stated file when the program ends? 2) Doesn't `setdefault` method adds `key: value` to the dictionary ONLY if the `key` doesn't exists? 3) B-b-but I like using camelCase... 4) I fixed the problem in my own code by changing the `cwd` back to the original one after the final loop ends

Comment: @Skullz 1) it closes when you exit the `with` scope. Wether that be by normal execution, or via an error. 2) Yes, ___that's what you're doing___. 3) Python programmers only use them for Classes...

Comment: hmm.. when I ran the first code you mentioned I got 
`num = names.setdafault(f_name, 1)
AttributeError: 'DbfilenameShelf' object has no attribute 'setdafault'`.
Doesn't that mean that shelves aren't really dictionaries in that regard?

Comment: @Skullz that's due to a late night typo. `setdafault` -> `setdefault`

Comment: oh my. I didn't notice it, sorry about that. It partially works now, but it still doesn't solve my main issue: the shelve files `.bak` and `.dat` are being copied into the destination `.zip`. Plus, an error is being produced `with _io.open(self._datfile, 'rb+') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'names.dat'`. I'd like to know how to fix this, but I'll update my post later with my final code either way. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Skullz A requirement of posting on Code Review is that your code works as you intend it to. We improve your code, but don't fix problems you have with your code. And so asking how to fix the `.bak` and `.dat` stuff is off-topic here. Also updating your code with the final code is also not allowed here, as it makes the Q&A format very confusing. :)